# Week end Date in netezza

Tags: netezza

I am looking for week start and end date in Netezza but my week starts from Mon and ends on Sun
Date          Week Start Date   Week End Date
11/30/2015    11/30/2015 Mon    12/06/2015 Sun

Answer (score 0):

`Day of Week` functions begin on Sunday in `Netezza`

[Template Patterns](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_templ_patterns_date_time_conv.html)
[Extract Function](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_functions_expressions_extract_datetime.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use modulo in order to deal with Sunday.

```
select
  current_date
  ,current_date - mod(extract(dow from current_date) - 2),7) week_start
  ,week_start + 6 week_end
```